# ...не те четыре элемента, что знает современная философия, – землю, воду, воздух и огонь, (–) а четыре элемента

Tags: пунктуация, тире

> Древние айлейды признавали не те четыре элемента, что знает современная натуральная философия, – землю, воду, воздух и **огонь, – а четыре** элемента религии высоких эльфов – землю, воду, воздух и свет.

Нужно ли тире в отмеченном месте и почему?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если после обособленного приложения (землю, воздух, воду и огонь) ставится запятая, то она "съедает" второе тире.

[ПРАВИЛО](https://www.portal-slovo.ru/philology/37430.php?ELEMENT_ID=37430&PAGEN_1=4)

При обособлении приложений можно употребить вместо запятых тире в следующих случаях:

> ...Для выделения с двух сторон приложений, носящих пояснительный
>   характер: *Самый старший из гномиков – добродушный толстячок по имени
>   Добряк – первым поприветствовал Белоснежку.*
>
> При этом второе тире может быть опущено:
>
> Если по условиям контекста после приложения должна стоять запятая:
>   *Если бы она не стала есть подарок незнакомой женщины – яблоко, то
>   никакой беды не случилось бы.* В данном случае второе тире "съедает"
>   запятая, разделяющая части сложного предложения.

Comment: Так понимаю, что съедает, если приложение короткое (в примерах лишь одно слово), а здесь нет (целый ряд приложений, уже имеющий запятые).

Comment: Розенталь - 8 пункт примечания: если приложение значительно распространено и имеет внутри себя запятые (ставится 2 тире).

Comment: Очень хорошо, спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрел этот пункт, но там совсем другая структура предложения: приложение между подлежащим и сказуемым.

Comment: Дело не в структуре, а, скорее всего, в наличии внутренних запятых. Во всех примерах (а их в справочниках Розенталя много) при отсутствии второго тире приложение содержит 1-2 слова без внутренних запятых.

Comment: Вот именно — внутренних запятых. У Розенталя запятая перед тире закрывает причастный оборот внутри приложения. Если приложение убрать, то никакой запятой не будет. А в нашем примере со стихиями запятая стоит перед противительным союзом "а", закрывает одну (цельную) часть предложения и начинает следующую.

Comment: И потом,  у Розенталя написано: "значительно распространено", а у нас всего лишь четыре коротких слова.

Comment: Это да. Но нужно больше смотреть на примеры. Розенталь формулировал правила и исключения на основе примеров. В нашем случае однородные приложения отделены запятыми (2 внутренние), а весь блок следует отделить чем-то большим. Должна же быть хоть какая-то пунктуационная дифференциация.

Answer (score 3):

*Древние айлейды признавали не те четыре элемента, что знает современная натуральная философия – **землю, воду, воздух и огонь**, а четыре элемента религии высоких эльфов – землю, воду, воздух и свет.*

Это предложение оформляется по правилу Розенталя для обособленных приложений, где сказано: второе тире не ставится, **если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая.**

Примечание. Следует различать правила обособления **приложений и вводных конструкций,** так как при обособлении вставок всегда ставится два тире, а выбирается только количество запятых. **Не следует смешивать**  два этих варианта (иначе получается **микс** из разных теорий и суждений, разобраться в котором было бы сложно и Розенталю).

Здесь более интересно отсутствие запятой, закрывающей придаточное предложение, например: https://iknigi.net/avtor-kollektiv-avtorov/162004-skayrim-tainstva-kollektiv-avtorov/read/page-8.html

Это, как я думаю, влияние новых тенденций. Отсутствие запятой показывает, что обособленный ряд относится **именно к придаточном**у.

Такой оформление выглядит **красиво и логично**, лишние тире и запятые только затемняют смысл.

Comment: Запятая должна закрывать придаточное. Не может ряд к нему относится. Просто опечатка. Не следует абсолютно доверять оригиналу. Автор явно взял его оттуда и захотел проверить. А здесь встроенная интонация не подходит, исходя из ударений: *Древние айлейды признавали не тЕ четыре элемента, что знает современная натуральная филосОфия, – землю, воду, воздух и огОнь, –...* Но: *Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весЫ, то понял бы источник ошИбки. Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой — аквалАнг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки мЕтров.*

Comment: oleedd, вот не успели появиться - и сразу меня критиковать.  Должен, не может, обязан следует... И кому же  все эти ряды и предложения  должны и обязаны? Вам и вашему пониманию проблемы, очевидно? А  такие опечатки я вижу сейчас в каждой ПЕРВОЙ книге. Запятая там чисто техническая, но при этом она затемняет структуру предложения. Ударение на "философии" не делаем, ряд привязываем к придаточному  после произносительной паузы, на него (на ряд) и падает ударение.  Объясняю понЯтно?

Comment: Вы же знаете, что "правило" запятой и тире сложное. Думаю, что не все авторы его полностью понимают. Но запятую принято оставлять, если подставляется слово ЭТО. А тенденция в том, что тире и так разделяет, мол, его и так хватает. Не привязывается оно так: хобот слона к мухе. Это конструктивная дискуссия, дружеская, сам Розенталь с коллегами спорил до покраснения. (Гораздо чаще я с вами согласен.)

Comment: Вопрос о запятой становится не праздным, если редактируешь текст. Ставить или не ставить - принимать такое решение приходится постоянно. Поэтому я особенно внимательно отслеживаю литературу с подобными предложениями.  У меня нет желания делать, как принято. Здесь ряд поясняет союзное слово ЧТО (КОТОРЫЕ) в большей степени, чем неопределенные "четыре элемента". И при чтении я бы соединила их, не стала бы разделять паузой.

Comment: Слово "что" - пустышка, которая ссылается на "те четыре элемента". Чем глубже "засовывать" этот ряд, тем второстепенней он становится. А это главная информация, которая должна быть с соответствующей интонацией.

Comment: Заблуждаетесь, однако. Слово ЧТО определяется  главной информацией, содержащейся в придаточном предложении. Поэтому и ряд относится к придаточному предложению.

Comment: Ряд должен относится к чему-то однозначно, безвариантно (по смыслу). Из-за того что придаточное поясняет определяемое понятие, вы относите определение (ряд) к придаточному - будто через посредника. Нет авторитетных примеров с отношением к слову ЧТО, когда по логике ряд относится к основной части (*четыре элемента - земля, вода, воздух и огонь*). Здесь вариантов нет. Это просто пропуск знака из-за незнания.

Comment: В таких случаях чётко есть 2 самостоятельные структуры - определяемое понятие и определение, стоящие по обе стороны тире. У вас так: *что знает современная натуральная философия – землю, воду, воздух и огонь*. Это урезанный, несамостоятельный фрагмент. Приложение не может относится к нему.

Comment: oleedd, успокойтесь и сосчитайте до десяти. Можете поставить запятую, если вам это по вкусу. Вы каждое предложение разбираете индивидуально, как бы сочиняете их сами. А вот современные лингвисты говорят о языковых моделях предложений с разным лексическом наполнением. Вот найдите мне похожую модель (такую ж структуру) у современного приличного автора, где стоит запятая, тогда я буду вам очень признательна.  А индивидуальные решения с длинными доказательствами вашей правоты меня интересуют меньше.

Answer (score -1):

Знаки препинания не съедают друг друга. Это чушь несусветная.

Тире и запятые поставлены по разным причинам.

Тире в предложении из вопроса находится там потому, что с двух сторон выделяет вставную конструкцию, уточняющую предшествующее высказывание.